# firewall vs Soap (electronic billing API)

Tags: networking, firewall, php, api, sophos

This is a complex question since it includes configuration and programming at the same time, but neither Sophos support nor the electronic billing service (consumer API) have given me an answer.

***context/scenario:***

I have an HP dedicated server with a LAMP setup in my office which, like all the computers, is behind a Sophos firewall and I am trying to consume **EXTERNAL** electronic billing API through the SOAP Client using PHP.

***The PHP scripts that are executed are the following:***

- enviroment:

```php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache", 0);
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
ini_set('max_input_time', -1);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600);
```

- for quality

```php
$url = 'https://url.com/ws/obj/v1.0/Service.svc?singleWsdl';
$ws = new SoapClient($url );
```

- for development

```php
$url = 'https://url.com/ws/obj/v1.0/Service.svc?singleWsdl';

$ws = new SoapClient($url , [
    'trace'              => true,
    'keep_alive'         => false,
    'connection_timeout' => 600,
    'cache_wsdl'         => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'compression'        => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
]);
```

- consumption of the method assigned by the api service:

```php
    $tokenCompany= '******************';
    $tokenPassword = '******************';

    $parametros = [
        'tokenEmpresa'  => $tokenCompany,
        'tokenPassword' => $tokenPassword,
        'documento'     => $bill,
    ];

    $result = $wsPa->__soapCall('Enviar', [$parametros]);
```

**result of execution outside the network (without firewall)**

- Last Request:

> kqyyyeverpza_tfhkal+?+X66Xd1d;000010101000000350012023-11-02T08:32:56-05:00011111111Prueba
> de Información de interés012155596713-2-201559FE generalAv.
> Balboa1-2-3Bocas del
> ToroChanguinolaGuabito997-8243wnunez@avipacinc.comPACuadernosTund1.002020-12-251410cm1.000.001.000.000.001.0000.0001.00000.000.000.00CuadernosTund1.002020-12-251410cm1.000.001.000.000.001.0000.0001.00000.000.000.002.000.000.000.002.402.400.00122.40022.40

- Header of the Request:

> string(273) "POST /ws/obj/v1.0/Service.svc HTTP/1.1 Host:
> url.com Connection: close User-Agent:
> PHP-SOAP/7.4.33 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Content-Type: text/xml;
> charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService/Enviar"
> Content-Length: 4516

- Last Response

> string(1189) "102errorEl documento está
> duplicadoFE0120000033159-58-250697-1000002023110200000000350010128662140712https://dgi-fep-test.mef.gob.pa:40001/Consultas/FacturasPorQR?chFE=FE0120000033159-58-250697-1000002023110200000000350010128662140712&iAmb=2&digestValue=OMl5rShuhLn3NPsqci+GgAIOmwrwAlEgupAz07KcM0Y=&jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjaEZFIjoiRkUwMTIwMDAwMDMzMTU5LTU4LTI1MDY5Ny0xMDAwMDAyMDIzMTEwMjAwMDAwMDAwMzUwMDEwMTI4NjYyMTQwNzEyIiwiaUFtYiI6IjIiLCJkaWdlc3RWYWx1ZSI6Ik9NbDVyU2h1aExuM05Qc3FjaStHZ0FJT213cndBbEVndXBBejA3S2NNMFk9In0.PPrSt0j7-CYWKY6U_cWl--YCSQtSFOh8Ujm_f_EuqY42023-11-02T07:11:430000155596713-2-201520230000000005329969"

- Response Header

> string(284) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2023 13:32:57 GMT
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 969 Connection:
> close Cache-Control: private Content-Encoding: gzip Vary:
> Accept-Encoding Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

**note:** What we are trying to evaluate is the communication, not whether the billing system correctly handles the document, see the next point.

**result of execution inside the network (with firewall) ERROR**

- Last Request:

> kqyyyeverpza_tfhkal+?+X66Xd1d;000010101000000350012023-11-02T08:32:56-05:00011111111Prueba
> de Información de interés012155596713-2-201559FE generalAv.
> Balboa1-2-3Bocas del
> ToroChanguinolaGuabito997-8243wnunez@avipacinc.comPACuadernosTund1.002020-12-251410cm1.000.001.000.000.001.0000.0001.00000.000.000.00CuadernosTund1.002020-12-251410cm1.000.001.000.000.001.0000.0001.00000.000.000.002.000.000.000.002.402.400.00122.40022.40

- Header of the Request:

> string(273) "POST /ws/obj/v1.0/Service.svc HTTP/1.1 Host:
> url.com Connection: close User-Agent:
> PHP-SOAP/7.4.33 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Content-Type: text/xml;
> charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService/Enviar"
> Content-Length: 4516

- Last Response

> NULL

- Response Header

> NULL

- Error Output:

> SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in
> /var/www/html/test.php:613 Stack trace:
> #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest()
> #1 /var/www/html/test.php(613): SoapClient->__soapCall()
> #2 {main}

***So I've reached the point where I don't know what to do, I thought about two things:***

- Determine if the Sophos firewall requires additional configuration to pass the API headers / response by transparent rule.
- Determine if need to add anything additional to the SOAP client configuration to prevent the firewall from blocking API consumption (response headers).

Neither support knows what to do, much less me, if anyone with experience has dealt with this I would appreciate at least a comment or response.

Comment: Of everything you asked me to do, I have no idea how to do it. :(

Comment: _Ensure you don't have any TLS/SSL issues:_ The physical server, as it is, can be accessed on the **LAN** through port 80. It is not visible from the Internet. I do not use SSL/TLS on the server, but I configured it so that it can obtain updates and consume the API, so it can access Internet resources. .

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I tried to do something with curl, but I couldn't find a way to reproduce the sending of data to the API with the "Send" method, I assume that I must have a connection to the API because of declaring the client, at that stage I have no problems with it WSDL file... until I try to consume it, and it is not something permanent, it is something sporadic, for example 6 out of 10 requests end with an error... the other 4 pass without problems.

Comment: I am clear that the problem is in the response of _$wsPa->__soapCall('Enviar', [$parametros]);_ I am figuring out how to solve it, according to the two possible approaches, from the firewall or from the php code.

Comment: I do have documentation but it is in Spanish [here](https://felwiki.thefactoryhka.com.pa/doku.php?id=lenguaje_php) and I personally consider it bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149475/discussion-between-vomit-it-chunky-mess-style-and-arcanisgk507).

Comment: Sounds good, tag me back when you have it added as a self-answer so I can check it out!!